# jbpm5 how to use the real user table

Tags: jbpm

This is salaboy example:

```
 private void addUsersAndGroups(TaskServiceSession taskSession) {
    User user = new User("salaboy");
    User watman = new User("watman");
    taskSession.addUser(user);
    taskSession.addUser(watman);
    User administrator = new User("Administrator");
    taskSession.addUser(administrator);
    users.put("salaboy", user);
    users.put("watman", watman);
    users.put("administrator", administrator);
    Group myGroup = new Group("group1");
    taskSession.addGroup(myGroup);
    groups.put("group1", myGroup);

}
```

I want use real *User Table*. How do I map it? How to use `UserGroupCallback` Interface? How users online custom processes, do they use *guvnor*?

Comment: Loogn did you achieve that. Could you plase give some information. it takes one day to search this is the first place that I see one that wants to use his own user table :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map your User class to a table, you need to create a user.hbm.xml file (you can follow [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic.html) tutorial in order to do so. This file will be placed on your META-INF folder